# Impractical problems in P

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, big-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Polynomial-time algorithms with huge exponent/constant](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/polynomial-time-algorithms-with-huge-exponent-constant)

In many texts you find statements like 'The class P characterizes the problems that are *efficiently* solvable. Even though $n^{100}$ algorithms are in P, these don't occur in practice'.

Today I came across a $n^{120}$ algorithm for a problem where, apparently, no better algorithm is known: Recognizing Map Graphs [Reference](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=00743490).

Then there are algorithms with huge constants like the graph minor algorithm.

Do you know of any other problems where the best known algorithm is polynomial, but terribly impractical?

Comment: Very similar to this question--at the very least there are some good answers in the responses here:  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/polynomial-time-algorithms-with-huge-exponent